# What is causing these spots on my shamrock plant?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care

We have had this shamrock at home (inside) for the last 4 months and about 1 month ago these spots started appearing. Any idea what it is and if we can fix it?[image: image of spots]

Comment: There are some little white flecks or bumps showing on the leaves at the very top of the picture - some along a vein of the leaf, but I can't tell what they are. Inspect those closely, with a magnifying glass if necessary. Also check beneath the leaves for invaders -  otherwise, is the plant in a pot with drainage holes? Has the soil been too wet at times?

Comment: The pot does not have drainage holes, and it's possible it has been too wet. It does get bright daylight all day, but not direct sunlight. I'll try to get a better picture of those other flecks you noticed, and I'll inspect closer too.